# How to display a Game Center leaderboard in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, gamekit

I'm pretty new to Swift and I'm having some trouble implementing a leaderboard into my game.

So far, I'm able to authenticate local player and set up leaderboard in iTunes Connect.

However, I'm unable to display the leaderboard itself, if I run the below code, it will abort when I click on GK Leaderboard button in SKScene. So, the question is how can I display the GK leaderboard from SKScene? Thanks!

GameViewController.swift

```
 import SpriteKit
 import GameKit

 class GameViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let scene = SceneMenu(size: view.frame.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    scene.backgroundColor = .white
    
    let view = view as! SKView
    view.presentScene(scene)

    view.showsFPS = true
    view.showsNodeCount = true

    authenticateLocalPlayer()

}

func authenticateLocalPlayer() {
    
    GKLocalPlayer.local.authenticateHandler = { viewController, error in
    
    }
    
}

func showLeaderboard() {
    
    let gcVC = GKGameCenterViewController(leaderboardID: "com.generic.leaderboard", playerScope: .global, timeScope: .allTime)
    gcVC.gameCenterDelegate = self
    present(gcVC, animated: true)
    
}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
    
    gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
    
}
}
```

SceneMenu.swift

```
import SpriteKit
import GameKit

class SceneMenu: SKScene {

override init(size: CGSize) {
    
    super.init(size: size)
    
    let btnGK = SKLabelNode(text: "GameKit")
    btnGK.name = "btn_gk"
    btnGK.fontSize = 20
    btnGK.fontColor = SKColor.blue
    btnGK.fontName = "Avenir"
    btnGK.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    addChild(btnGK)
    
    let btnLeaderboard = SKLabelNode(text: "GK Leaderboard")
    btnLeaderboard.name = "btn_leaderboard"
    btnLeaderboard.fontSize = 20
    btnLeaderboard.fontColor = SKColor.blue
    btnLeaderboard.fontName = "Avenir"
    btnLeaderboard.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2 - 50)
    addChild(btnLeaderboard)
    
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
    if let touch = touches.first {
        
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let action = atPoint(location)
        
        switch action.name {
            
        case "btn_gk":
            
            print("btn_gk")
           
            GKLeaderboard.submitScore(10, context: 0, player: GKLocalPlayer.local, leaderboardIDs: ["com.generic.leaderboard"]) { _ in }
          
        case "btn_leaderboard":
            
            print("btn_leaderboard")
            
            GameViewController().showLeaderboard()
  
        default:
            
            print("nothing")
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can’t provide any code right now but what you really should be doing is using something like UIKit to create a UIView for the leader board and then embed that into a SKScene.

There is an interface something like SKView that is backed by a UIView which makes this fairly easy to do.

Keep Sprite Kit for the game stuff. Use UIKit for the UI stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, however I'd like to use SpriteKit for now. And I would appreciate for a solution that works with SpriteKit :)

Comment: I can see some old examples (from 6+ years ago) where they use rootViewController but it doesn't work for me.

for example: 
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/16577

Comment: You already have a UIViewController (GameViewController) why would it not work for you to create a UIView for this? It would certainly be easier than rendering it in SpriteKit.

Comment: I'm sure it will work, however I'm trying to focus on learning Swift and next APIs first: SpriteKit/StoreKit/UserNotifications/UserDefaults/GameKit/CloudKit. I'm already overwhelmed with amount of things that I need to learn.

Comment: I have a working solution now... I added this code to SKScene and it open the GK leaderboard:

let vc = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
                let gcVC = GKGameCenterViewController(leaderboardID: "com.generic.leaderboard", playerScope: .global, timeScope: .allTime)
                vc.present(gcVC, animated: true)

However, I am sure there must be better solution, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're on the right track, at least that's how I did it.  Remember to handle Game Center authentication/deauthentication in enabling/disabling the high score button.  And if you've got other stuff going on, you may want to pause while showing `gcVC`.